# netcore 2.2 подключить стороннюю библиотеку на NetFramework 4.5.2

Tags: c#, c++, qt, asp.net-core

Для проекта на netcore 2.2 понадобилось использовать библиотеку скомпилированную под X86 NetFramework 4.5.2
Библиотека это обертка над С++ (Qt).
Библиотека нормально работала для WinForms (под X86 NetFramework 4.5.2).

Версия netcore x64 на продакшене, поэтому попросил разрабов пере собрать под X64.

Разработчики там ленивые и могут отбрить)) я заранее хочу все варианты понять.

1. А можно им пере собрать под netcore 2.2 (x64)
2. Если будет под X64 NetFramework 4.5.2 - нормально ли запустится на netcore 2.2?

информация про сборку

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;

// Assembly LedScreenLibNetWrapper, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0ba943bd8ad3b6d1
// MVID: 62773361-C1A1-44D9-AA06-BDF34E2154E3
// Assembly references:
// mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
// System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
// Module references:
// LedScreenLib1.dll

[assembly: CompilationRelaxations(8)]
[assembly: RuntimeCompatibility(WrapNonExceptionThrows = true)]
[assembly: Debuggable(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints)]
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("LedScreenLibNetComWrapper")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("LedScreenLibNetComWrapper")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("SibLed")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("LedScreenLibNetComWrapper")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2017")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]
[assembly: Guid("5c3ecc53-aa5a-4b04-87db-22af4777e5ec")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: TargetFramework(".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2", FrameworkDisplayName = ".NET Framework 4.5.2")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Comment: Что то я сомневаюсь, что вы сможете подключить либу на .Net FW 4.5.2 к проекту .Net Core 2.2, думаю, они не совместимы.

Comment: А как им сформулировать задание чтобы они сбилдили совместимую либу?

Comment: Зависимости их Либы LedScreenLib1.dll (на C++) это библиотеки Qt: (Qt5Core.dll и Qt5Network.dll). И вот для  LedScreenLib1.dll они делают com обертку LedScreenLibNetWrapper.dll - которая мне и нужна. Т.е. завсимостей от .Net FW 4.5.2  прямых нету.

Comment: Если они могут скомпилировать свой код под .Net Core или .Net Standard, то вы можете попытаться его к себе вкрутить, если нет - то нет.

Comment: @tym32167 ну подключить сборку .NET Framework к .NET Core можно, и даже компилироваться и работать будет, но там целая куча условий, в том числе по зависимостям, так что действительно, проще считать что так нельзя.

Comment: @rdorn я могу ошибаться, не слежу за темой, но .Net Core вроде есть разные, есть кроссплатформенная, которая на линуксе работает, она навряд ли COM поддерживает, есть полная, которая только на Windows, там есть поддержка COM, но вот о поддержке полного фреймворка с СОМ прослойкой я не слышал.

Comment: @tym32167 так полный и не поддерживается в прямом смысле. Сборки можно использовать, но все зависимости придется прибивать гвоздями, т.к. core ничего не знает ни про какой GAC. Но даже в этом случае далеко не все заработает. Ну и в любом случае такие извращения только для Win.

Comment: Если либа примитивная, посмотрите на QmlNet.

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае ответ будет: нет, библиотека собранная для .NET Framework с .NET Core ни какой версии работать не будет. Не говоря уже о возможной разнице в архитектуре (x86|x64).

Подобные связки компилируются без ошибок, если руками прописать все связи в проекте (включая неявные зависимости) и, **в исключительных случаях**, даже могут работать, но кроссплатформенность практически исключена и надежность под большим вопросом.

Вашу библиотеку нужно повторно собирать именно для .NET Core или, хотя бы, NET Standard, что, скорее всего, потребует изменить часть существующего кода, т.к. библиотеки базовых классов у .NET Framework и .NET Core отличаются, местами существенно.

Ну и остается открытым вопрос об использовании COM. Если целевая платформа windows, то ни каких вопросов, а с *nix будут проблемы, хотя вроде как были попытки прикрутить COM к *nix, но получилось ли что-то кроме эмулятора Wine, я не в курсе.

Comment: Целевая платформа Linux в Docker. Тогда вопрос как они пере соберут свои Qt библиотеки (которые скорее всего кросплатформленные) под net core? Обертка нужна чтобы только из .net дотянутся до Api их либы. Никаких зависимостей именно от NET Framework  думаю они не юзают

Comment: @Aldmi ну это уже не ко мне вопрос. Я же не знаю что там за библиотека.

Comment: Я могу их попросить сбилдить либу для Linux под x64. Далее мне самому нужно написать обертку для netcore. Какие мои шаги?

Comment: @Aldmi Давайте это лучше отдельным вопросом. Во-первых, лично я такое сам не делал, т.к. в основном пишу под Win. Во-вторых. тут так принято, один топик - один вопрос.

Comment: Ок, спасибо за обсуждения. Спрошу у Разрабов, что они смогут с этим сделать. Потом уже про новый вопрос подумаю.